# Sitecore Rocks : Random Serialization Folders

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

Due to the limitation of windows file path, Sitecore creates some random directory in the serialization folder for the sitecore content items.

This works well when we revert using the sitecore content editor, but not working while using Sitecore Rocks.

Sitecore rocks installs only the items in the correct path and skips the items in the random folders.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are running the latest version.  If you are, then create a ticket at http://sitecorerocks.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks, even sitecore support suggested to raise it in the forums. Let me try this.